# Golang in Vim - Tagbar plugin shows incorrect places

Tags: go, vim, tagbar

I've installed **vim-go** with all needed binaries, added **tagbar** plugin from `https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar`, **gotags** and **ctags** binaries exist in may $PATH.

The problem is that some functions/variables redirect me to the absolutely wrong line (same for multiple tagbar's functions), and some of them works properly. I can't open even **main()** function in a current project. And I don't see the differences in **tagbar**/code among these functions/objects.

This is also added to the `.vimrc`:

```
let g:tagbar_type_go = {  
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'go',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'p:package',
        \ 'i:imports:1',
        \ 'c:constants',
        \ 'v:variables',
        \ 't:types',
        \ 'n:interfaces',
        \ 'w:fields',
        \ 'e:embedded',
        \ 'm:methods',
        \ 'r:constructor',
        \ 'f:functions'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro' : '.',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 't' : 'ctype',
        \ 'n' : 'ntype'
    \ },
    \ 'scope2kind' : {
        \ 'ctype' : 't',
        \ 'ntype' : 'n'
    \ },
    \ 'ctagsbin'  : 'gotags',
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-sort -silent'
\ }
```

Please help to make **tagbar** work properly, what am I missing?

Comment: Please run gotags manually in a terminal to check whether its output is correct (the gotags documentation should explain how to do that). If the output is incorrect you should create an issue for that project. If the output is correct, but Tagbar's behaviour is incorrect, then please create an issue in Tagbar's issue tracker and provide debug logs as explained in `:h tagbar-issues`.

Comment: Oh, looks like you've just done that, so ignore this comment.